# Запятая

Tags: пунктуация

"И в делах и в личной жизни считает взаимное доверие нормой отношений" — тут нужна запятая после "в делах" или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При повторяющемся союзе "и" запятая ставится: *и в делах, и в личной жизни...*